# How can i post an inner form?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an inner form say frm2 as follows...

```
<form id ="frm1" action="test.php" method="post">
  <form id="frm2" action="test2.php" method="post">

    //some text fields and a button
  </form>

</form>
```

How can I submit test2.php individually without submitting test.php?

Comment: you should not use nested form at any cases.It is not a valid process

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid, according to the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)

> Content model:
>       Flow content, but with **no form element descendants**.